# Do not duplicate dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-library

I have a library with next dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.2'
```

Now I need to add the same dependencies to the my main project with this library.

How can I implement the library so that all these dependencies are not duplicated in the main project?

Right now in my project i write:

```
implementation 'com.mandarine.sdk:mandarine-library:2.0.1@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'  
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'    
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.2'//Don't update while support Android SDK < 20
```

And in library:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.2'
```

**Update:**
Also tried write in my project next:

```
api 'com.mandarine.sdk:mandarine-library:2.0.1@aar'
```

And modified my library like this:

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:17.0.0'
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
api 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
api 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.2'
```

Unfortunately also doesn't work.

Comment: Leave the work for gradle to handle. Just make sure you are referencing the same version your library is also referencing. Gradle will do the merging and there won't be duplicates. You only need to exclude if there are version mismatch or class conflicts.

Comment: @GiddyNaya  version is correct
but if I remove these dependencies then the app will crash

Comment: And what error do you get using the dependencies on your project?

Comment: @GiddyNaya https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/e0269a1f1b2a5062c6c16beb8329d268

Comment: try enabling Multidex on the project then clean and rebuild project

Comment: @GiddyNaya I still use the retrofit why would I want to use multidex?...
clean/rebuild project doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved problem with next solution:

```
implementation ('com.saltedge.sdk:saltedge-library:2.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

This helped me use dependencies in the library, and do not duplicate them in the main project.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the dependencies from each library that you do not want to include

```
implementation('com.your.library') {
    exclude module: 'library1'
    exclude module: 'library2'
}
```

Comment: exclude module: 'library1' ? for example it s my retorfit?

Comment: exclude module: 'retrofit2'

Comment: the idea is not to declare dependencies in the project itself, but to use those that are in the library.
What's the point of excluding them?

Comment: So remove the ones declared in your project then.

Comment: If i remove retrofit2 for example, i get the next error
https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/e0269a1f1b2a5062c6c16beb8329d268